# Cocos2 code structure question

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am doing tutorials to learn Cocos2d and have a question. here is the .m code:

```
#import "SceneManager.h"

@interface SceneManager ()
   +(void) go: (CCLayer *) layer;
   +(CCScene *) wrap: (CCLayer *) layer;
@end


@implementation SceneManager

    +(void) goPlay {
        CCLayer *layer = [PlayLayer node];
        [SceneManager go: layer];
}

+(void) go: (CCLayer *) layer {
    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];
    CCScene *newScene = [SceneManager wrap:layer];

//    Class transition = nextTransition();

    if ([director runningScene]) {
         [director replaceScene:newScene];
}else {
    [director runWithScene:newScene];
}
}

+(CCScene *)wrap: (CCLayer *) layer {
    CCScene *newScene = [CCScene node];
    [newScene addChild: layer];
    return newScene;
}

@end
```

My question is why is there an @interface placed in the .m file and not included in the .h file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `@interface Class ()` placed in the implementation file is a [class extension](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2009/09/11/class-extensions-explained/) to the SceneManager class which defines its **private interface**.

It's being used because `go` and `wrap` are only used by the implementation of this class and nowhere else (i.e. it's a private interface).

The `@private` modifier only works on variables, not on methods, so this is the way to *hide* them.

(Source: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/651852/1086334))